# Internationalization with 'date_select' helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I used scaffold to make the entire CRUD structure, and the month selection fields of `date_section` helper are all English:

[image]

The code of `view/_form.html.erb` is like this.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :start_date, :order=>[:year, :month, :day]%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :end_date, :order=>[:year, :month, :day]%>
  </div>
```

The majority of my site's users don't use English. So I want to modify this `January`, `February`, .... to other text like `1`,`2`,`3`,....

How should I modify this code?

Comment: Can you try this - <%= f.date_select :start_date, :order => [ :day, :month, :year ], :use_month_numbers => true %>
You can also check this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select)

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna That's what i want. Thanks a lot :D.